# Como cambiar el name de un radio automaticamente?

Tags: php

Buenas noches, espero puedan ayudarme tengo este while dentro de otro while y este se muestra 5 por cada fila, asi que necesito que su name cambie en cada fila, no se si me explico

```
<?php include("cabeceras/sesion.php"); ?>

<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['rol'])) { 
if ($_SESSION['rol'] == "3") {

 ?>
 <div class="container well">
    <h2 class="text-center">Registro de notas</h2>
 </div>

   <form action="#" method="POST">
     <div class="container well">
 <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
        <tr>
            <td class="alert-danger">N°</td>
            <td class="alert-success">Indicadores</td>
            <?php 
            include_once("conexion/conexion.php");
            $con=conectar();
            $consulta="SELECT * FROM ponderaciones";
            $consultar=$con->query($consulta);
            while ($row1=$consultar->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

              echo '<td class="alert-info">'.$row1['ponderacion'].'</td>';
            }
             ?>

        </tr>

        <?php 
        include_once("conexion/conexion.php");
        $con=conectar();
        $id_docente=$_SESSION['id_docente'];
        $count=1;
        $sql="SELECT * FROM indicadores";
        $sqlr=$con->query($sql);
        while ($row=$sqlr->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

            ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $count; $count++; ?></td>
                <td class="text-left"><input name="id_indicador" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id_indicador']; ?>"><?php echo $row['indicador']; ?></td>

                <?php 
                $consulta="SELECT * FROM ponderaciones";
                $consultar=$con->query($consulta);
                echo '<fieldset>';
                while ($row3=$consultar->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
                echo '<legend>Ponderacion</legend>';
                 echo '<td><input name="id_ponderacion" if("'.$row3['id_ponderacion'].'"=="A") {echo "checked"} type="radio" value="'.$row3['id_ponderacion'].'"> </td>';
                }
                echo ' </fieldset>';
                 ?>

            </tr>
    <?php  
        }
         ?>

</table>

    </div>

    <div class="container well text-center">
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="Limpiar">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Registrar Evaluación">
    </div>

      </form>

<?php include("cabeceras/pie.php"); ?>

<?php } else { ?>   
        <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
        alert('USTED NO TIENE ACCESO A ESTA PARTE DE LA PAGINA')  
        document.location.href='index.php'   
        </script> 
<?php } } else { ?>
        <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
        alert('USTED NO TIENE ACCESO A ESTA PAGINA')  
        document.location.href='conexion/logout.php'     
        </script> 
<?php } ?>

<?php 

$id_alumno=$_GET['id_alumno'];
$id_indicador=$_POST['id_indicador'];
$id_inponderacion=$_POST['id_ponderacion'];

echo $id_inponderacion;
echo "<br>";
var_dump($_POST);
 ?>
```

[image: En la imagen pueden ver los radio para que puedan entenderme mejor]

Comment: actualmente solo me deja seleccionar uno solo por toda la tabla, deberia seleccionar uno por fila y se muestran 5 radio por fila

Comment: Hay algun `for` de nivel superior ?

Comment: @EmanuelVe amigo no tengo ningún for, alli acabo de subir una imagen para que puedas ver los radio

Comment: Me refiero al bucle que muestra todas las filas, podrias sacar algun ID de ahi y usarlo para generar el `name` del `radio`. Asi de paso, podras identificarlo bien en el lado servidor.

Comment: Te refieres a sacar el id del bucle padre y usarlos en el bucle hijo algo asi? yo te entiendo, pero no se si tu me estas entendiendo a mi @EmanuelVe

Comment: Te parece si coloco el código completo?

Comment: Puede ser. ..haha.. es la 1am. Aver.. tienes N filas y en cada una 5 `radio`. El radio de cada fila debe llamarse diferente de las demas pero igual en cada fila ¿correcto?

Comment: colocalo completo de ambos while (a eso me referia con lo del for)

Comment: asi es amigo, eso es lo que deseo hacer

Comment: Ya subí el código completo, alli puedes ver ambos bucles @EmanuelVe

Comment: ví que editaste el código y la verdad no comprendo, solo vi que marcaste el html, no puedo subir html? es mi primer post aqui @EmanuelVe

Comment: Jor, solo corregi el formato, estoy escribiendo una respuesta. paciencia ;)

Comment: ah esta bien amigo, tranquilo, solo pensaba que me había hecho mal el post o algo. Esperare...

Comment: Pruebalo y me cuentas, ya me estoy llendo a dormir que es tarde aca. Si tenes alguna duda, tendra que ser mañana. Salu2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lugar de usar un campo `hidden` como este:

```
<input name="id_indicador" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id_indicador']; ?>">
```

El cual, repite el `name` y no te servirá de mucho al enviar el formulario ya que no te dice cual a cual grupo de `radio` esta asociado. Puedes usar el `id_indicador` como subfijo de los radio button. Ojo, este es un enfoque entre varios diferentes posibles:

Donde tienes el bucle de las `ponderaciones`, cambia el `name` del `<input>`.

```
<input name="resultado[<?php echo $row['id_indicador']; ?>]"
```

Con esta estructura en tu `$_POST` recibirás un array símil este:

```
array(2) { ["resultado"]=> 
                  array(3) { 
                     [1]=> string(1) "1" 
                     [2]=> string(1) "3" 
                     [3]=> string(1) "3" 
                  } 
           ["submit"]=> string(20) "Registrar Evaluación" 
}
```

El truco de esto es que *php* convierte los elementos con esta sintaxis en su name en arrays auto-magicamente. Me refiero a cuando tenemos elementos con nombres `name="resultado[1]"`, `name="resultado[2]"`.. etc. Por lo que es una gran ayuda.

No te preocupes si los ids se saltean o están desordenados, llegaran correctamente. Solo asegúrate de usar ids numéricos.

Luego solo tienes que loopear sobre el:

```
foreach ($_POST['resultado'] as $id_indicador => $id_ponderacion) {
    // para cada $id_indicador el $id_ponderacion seleccionado
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: me funcionó, pero ahora el problema es que no me toma el $id_indicador para realizar el insert a la bd

Comment: @jorgnv Quieres decir que dento del `foreach` el valor de $id_indicador no es valido?

Answer (score 0):

prueba a crear un contador el cual se autoincremente y lo concatenas al nombre con eso tendras un identificador autonumerico al recoger recoreras con un for el numero de elementos y los puedes insertar en BD uno por uno.

```
$contador = 0;
while ($row3=$consultar->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
                echo '<legend>Ponderacion</legend>';
                 echo '<td><input name="id_ponderacion" if("'.$row3['id_ponderacion'].'"=="A") {echo "checked"} type="radio" value="'.$row3['id_ponderacion'].$contador'"> </td>';
$contador++;
                }
```